# Communication between 2 containers in 2 different Azure VMs in same subnet

Tags: azure, docker, networking, ip

I have 2 Azure VMs.
In each VM,

1. there are 2 secondary interfaces (apart from primary one)
2. I have moved the 2 n/w interfaces into the container using "ip netns exec" cmd.

After this I am unable to have successful ping between 2 containers using secondary interfaces.

Any pointers here will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the secondary interfaces have been correctly moved into the container and assigned valid IP addresses. You can use the ip addr command in the container to check this.
Ensure that the network security group (NSG) associated with the secondary interfaces allows ICMP traffic (ping) between the virtual machine IP addresses. If the NSG blocks ICMP traffic, you will not be able to ping.

Comment: I have allowed ping in NSG. Also verified that ip address is assigned to the interfaces.
and added the required routes using ip route add cmd